# 2D Graphic library for using on server

Tags: c++, c, linux, image, static-libraries

I'm looking for simple C/C++ graphic library which can easy do: resizing, croping, grayscaling, etc. with images. Main requirement is easy installation (best from source) on server (linux-debian)  because I'm not root on the server and common libraries like ImageMagick or OpenCV failed on installation process because there wasn't CMake, old autoconf etc.

Comment: Replicate the existing server toolchain on your home system, compile, make install to ~, move to server?

Comment: Server admin install the ImageMagick. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://cimg.sourceforge.net/ very simple to use and the source code is available.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at liuliu's ccv library, a lightweight alternative to opencv

https://github.com/liuliu/ccv

Comment: Sorry, that was an auto-posted comment this seems perfectly valid :)

Comment: ah, cool, you got a karma-mining bot there ;)

Comment: Nah (good idea though! :P), was just looking through the review queue and link only was suggested, seemed appropriate to flag but didn't see the whole context was *looking* for libraries :D

Answer (score 0):

[Skia](https://code.google.com/p/skia/wiki/APIOverview) looks promising (have not used)